# Zend route regex problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, multilingual, zend-route

I'm developing a **multilanguage Zend project**. I am creating events so I wanna use a structure like this:

- domain.com/event/2010/ => Events on year 2010
- domain.com/event/2010/11/ => Events on november 2010
- domain.com/event/2010/11/23/ => Events on november, 23th 2010

For this pourpuse I created the following routes:

```
$router->addRoute('event', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('event/(\d+)(/(\d+)(/(\d+))?)?', array(
                    'module' => 'public',
                    'controller' => 'event',
                    'action' => 'show'
                )));

$router->addRoute('eventLang', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(':language/event/(\d+)(/(\d+)(/(\d+))?)?', array(
                    'language'=>'en'
                    'module' => 'public',
                    'controller' => 'event',
                    'action' => 'show'
                )));
```

The first one works perfect. the second one display an error like "action 2010 does not exists". What is the problem here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables (`:language` in your case) in Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex. You should rewrite your regexp in next way:

```
$router->addRoute('eventLang', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('[^/]+/event/(\d+)(/(\d+)(/(\d+))?)?', array(
    'module' => 'public',
    'controller' => 'event',
    'action' => 'show'
), array(
    1 => 'language'
));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I wanna know if I can stablish if a string have more than 3 characters in regex. Something like: [a-z]{3+}

Comment: Sure you can write ([a-z]{3+})